# Use Of Strict CSP Grid View Integration In .NET MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, content-security-policy, owasp

We need to replace a Kendo Grid view used in our MVC5 application due to **Strict CSP compliance** and we are looking for a grid replacement but hard to find which is a **strict CSP compliance**. Can anybody help and suggest a grid for this replacement.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wish to find something such powerful as Kendo UI, there is no way because any powerful libs will use some "CSP-unsafe" constructs anyway. Even Google Tag Manager requires 'unsafe-inline' and in some cases - 'unsafe-eval'.
2. <s>Some "CSP-unsafe" is not Kendo's but third-party JS libs. For example, used by Kendo the [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) javascript library requires 'unsafe-eval', but it's this lib's 'trouble', not Kendo. Any other GRids will use the same lib or equal and no one ensures those will be totally "CSP-safe".</s>
   **updated:** detailed reserches shown that Kendo UI **do use unsafe eval expressions**, but JSZip.js - do not.

You may too have some "CSP-unsafe" code written by your own while embedding the Kendo Grid.

3. Unfortunately you did not disclose what is a "Strict CSP compliance" you need. This greatly reduces the chances to get your question detaily answered.

> 

The [Content security Policy for Kendo UI Grid](http://csplite.com/csp/test303/) requires potentially "unsafe":

- 'unsafe-inline' in the `style-src` directive, this is unavoidable.
- 'unsafe-inline' in the `script-src` directive, <s>this is not avoidable by easy way because of inline event handlers. But those appears not in each browser and locks of those do not have visual affects (it requires the additional research of code).</s> **updated:** Kendo UI itself **do not use unsafe-inline** in scripts at all.
- 'unsafe-eval' in the `script-src` directive, <s>this is avoidable - just remove "Export to Excel" button in user template.</s> this is unavoidable, Kendo UI uses a lot of `Function()` constructs, these requited 'unsafe-eval'

But any other Grids with powerful UI (except `<table>...</table>` and server side rendering, of course) will have the same troubles.
You still could have safe enough CSP for Kendo UI. <s>Also I would write to the JSZip developers (with reference to this thread), maybe they can get rid of the `new Function` construct. It will make CSP for Kendo UI much safe in future.</s> (pls see **updates** above).

Changing one library to another one is a serious waste of time, and no one guarantees that this other will remain with "Strict CSP compliance" in future.

PS: I did update some details after detailed reserches Kendo UI. It was my fault, sorry about that.